# .net Core connected services System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException after moving to windows 10 development machine

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, soap, connected-services

My company is currently moving from windows 7 to windows 10. I've been trying to debug one of our .NET core projects which is calling soap services using connected services. 
when I get to the point of making the call it throws the exception:

`System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (407) authenticationrequired.`

no code changes were made from it working on my windows 7. I can call the soap services using postman and in code using a html request but changing all request in the project to that at the moment isn't an ideal option as its a large change to the project. my proxy settings seem to be the same.

Comment: The HTTP status code error 407 is a proxy error.  Are you using a certificate?  Did you change version of Net.  Best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the first request from Postman with first request in c#.  Then make the headers in c# look like headers in postman.  The default headers in Net are different from Postman.

Comment: no the thing is nothing has changed in the project at all. I was given a windows 10 box to replace my windows 7 box pulled down the latest and went to debug and got the 407. so I just tried running fiddler in the background and it successfully made the soap request. I closed fiddler and the request failed again. I've compared my proxy settings between my 2 boxes and they look to be the same

Comment: Did you capture the first http request from Postman and compare to c#?

Comment: sorry I didnt realise i had notifications turned off, as i said in my comment above it works when fiddler is running but not when it is not

Comment: You need to debug with a sniffer to find out what is working and not working.  I'm suspecting that the version of SSL/TLS has changes, but it could be anything.  Fiddler should attempt to try different versions of SSL/TLS until it finds the one that works.  The c# code will only try the options programmed.  The TLS/SSL is done using TCP.  You should be able to see in fiddler the TLS/SSL options in both working and non working connection.